# Force a full PostBack from an <ItemTemplate> inside a <GridView> in an UpdatePanel

Tags: asp.net, updatepanel, postback, linkbutton

I found this solution to force full postbacks from within an `UpdatePanel`:

```
<Triggers>
    <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="controlID" />
 </Triggers>
```

But my `control` is actually inside an `ItemTemplate` nested in a `GridView`. Therefore when my page loads, it doesn't find that control.

How can I force a full postback from my control (an asp:`LinkButton`) from within my `GridView`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try getting the control in the OnRowDatabound event of the gridview and use the scriptmanager to register the postback control.  Haven't tried this but I think it should work...

```
var control = e.Row.FindControl("YourControlID");
if(control != null)
    ScriptManager.RegisterPostbackControl(control);
```

Comment: I have a grid within UpdatePanel and I wanted postback on a link within..I did the same as above but on first load link is working but else no. What could I be missing..?